# Create same LINQ anonymous type from different XML element

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I have an XML file like this:-
[image: XML file]

Notice that each `<Field></Field>` can have different element like the highlighted `<I32>` or `<String>`. I want to show the element name in a datagridview like this which Type is for the name of element (either I32 or String or other child element of `<Field>`) :-
[image: Datagridview]

So far, I've tried this code but it return `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("GetLotDetails.xml");
var data = doc.Descendants("Document").Where(x => (String)x.Attribute("name") == "DATA").SelectMany(x => x.Elements("Field"));
var query = from d in data
            let str = d.Element("String").Name
            let other = d.Element("I32").Name
            select new
            {
                 Name = d.Attribute("name").Value,
                 Type = str.Equals("String") ? "String" : (other.Equals("I32") ? "I32" : null),        
                 Value = d.Value,
            };
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

So the idea is to let the anonymous `Type = *whatever element name under field*`. How can I extracted different name of element in the LINQ select statement and give it to the same unknown type variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with anonymous types. You are missing a null check

```
var query = 
    from d in data
    let element = d.Element("String") ?? d.Element("I32")
    select new
    {
        Name = d.Attribute("name").Value,
        Type = element?.Name,
        d.Value
    };
```

In your original query, you unconditionally read the `Name` from both possible nodes, but for any given `d`, one of the nodes will be `null`. I could have written it using the null conditional operator, `d.Element("String")?.Name`, but the above is more readable in this context as the additional projection in your original query adds noise and potential confusion.

Comment: thank you. it works now. I should understand the logic of `null` better. (-.-)"